# How to remember / autofill forms with uzbl

Tags: password, browser

I'm using [uzbl](http://www.uzbl.org/) to listen radio online, including this French [web radio](http://www.ledjamradio.com/). There's a simple email/password form I would like to be filled automatically (down-right corner link `"Se connecter"`).

Less specifically, I can't find some clear doc about how to remember forms with `uzbl`.

I found a [script](http://www.uzbl.org/wiki/paranoid-formfiller) for storing encrypted passwords, although I really don't need encryption for now, and it doesn't say how to actually store/auto-fill forms.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with uzbl, but the [Readme](http://www.uzbl.org/readme.php) seems to allow for an external script to take a URL as input and take user/pass as output.

Comment: Thanks, It's definitely what I'm looking for. But it seems a bit complicated. I'm going to try on my own, but further help would be great.

Comment: Based on a quick look at the web radio site, it looks like I'm probably wrong about using the HTTP auth script; you are probably closer with auto-filling the form. Sorry I can't be more help!